# grid data change dynamically inside Fragment inside Sliding tab on click

Tags: android, datagrid, tabs, android-viewpager, pagerslidingtabstrip

I have a sliding tab layout where i have 3 tabs and a navigation drawer. Each tab is a fragment. now i want to use one fragment as a cardview in a grid manner. but my problem is when i click navigation drawer item my tab fragment grid data is not changing.

[image]

here is the link of my code structure.

https://github.com/rrrongon/NavigationDrawerwithTab

Answer (score 0):

Use event bus for achieve this. when you click on menu item fire an event and than listen that event to your respective fragment and on listen do your respective work